# Primefaces Dialog action is called during initialisation

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish, primefaces

I have a simple JSF Dialog which is included in the page like:

```
<ui:include src="add.xhtml"/>
```

In this dialog I have a `<p:commandButton>` which is executed without having been clicked...

```
<p:dialog id="spidDialog" header="New SPID Operator" widgetVar="add">
    <h:form>
        <p:messages id="errorMsg" showDetail="true"/>  
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="addGrid">
            <h:outputText style="font-size: smaller;" value="SPID Operator Name" />
            <p:inputText id="Name" value="#{sBean.selectedName}" required="true"/>
            <h:outputText style="font-size: smaller;" value="SPID Operator Code" />
            <p:inputText id="Code" value="#{sBean.selectedCode}" required="true" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{sBean.save(actionEvent)}" 
                         oncomplete="handleDialog('spidDialog', args,add);"
                         update="editOperatorTabForm:Div growl editOperatorTabForm:Table"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="add.hide();" immediate="true"/>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

The action `#{sBean.save(actionEvent)}` causes a NullPointerException but it should not be called during initialization.  It is being called without any user interaction, should that be the case?

Comment: The actionListener of a command button should only be invoked on a user generated click event or through a custom Javascript of some sort.  If `sBean.save` is being executed on page initialization then something else must be calling that method.

Comment: ... Also, you do not need to specify the ActionEvent argument for the `actionListener` attribute.  This will work just as well, `#{sBean.save}`

Answer (score 2):

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{sBean.save(actionEvent)}" ...>
```

This expression syntax is incorrect for an `actionListener`. It is been evaluated as a value expression instead of a method expression. You need to remove the `(actionEvent)` part.

```html
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{sBean.save}" ...>
```